# Will compilers optimize out unused private methods?

Tags: java, javac, compiler-optimization, private-methods

Does javac leave out private methods if they are inlined?
For example

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(sayHello());
  }
  private static String sayHello(){
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

But what if this method is then accessed by reflection?

```
 System.out.println(Test.class.getMethod("sayHello").invoke(null));
```

How does the compiler know whether to inline the method and remove it or not?

Comment: What makes you think this method is being inlined by the compiler? It does no inlining. Inlining might happen at runtime, in the JIT compiler.

Comment: You can try it out for yourself by disassembling the compiled class using `javap`. It will most likely not discard the method.

Comment: Compiler optimizations never change behavior.

Comment: *"Does `javac` leave out private methods ..."* - No.  Not under any circumstances.  And `javac` doesn't do inlining anyway.  (You can check both of these things for yourself using `javap`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have followed user Jesper's suggestion and used javap on this code:

```
package stackoverflow;

public class CompilerOptimize {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(sayHello());
    }

    private static String sayHello(){
        return "Hello World";
    }

    private static void bananas() {
        System.out.println("Monkey!");
    }
}
```

Method `sayHello` is used and `bananas` is not.

The result of running javap with the -p parameter on the compiled class with Java 8 is:

```
public class stackoverflow.CompilerOptimize {
  public stackoverflow.CompilerOptimize();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: invokestatic  #3                  // Method sayHello:()Ljava/lang/String;
       6: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       9: return

  private static java.lang.String sayHello();
    Code:
       0: ldc           #5                  // String Hello World
       2: areturn

  private static void bananas();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #6                  // String Monkey!
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

The method `bananas` is mentioned in the byte code comments (`sayHello` is there too).

> Will compilers optimize out unused private methods?

Not really.

Comment: @JB Nizet: shame on me. Many thanks for pointing out that the -p parameter was missing. You deserve some credit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never realized that javac didn't do any optimizing! Seems like missed opportunity though

Comment: Seems Android's Java-op-code optimizations work better by far, I mean, even always false if-block's code is removed (beside unused methods being removed).